# Error with custom plyr function for aggregating "Mindware" files

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

Apologies for not having a reproducible example- this involves multiple individual files and I'm not sure how to create an example for this issue.

I'm using a function to aggregate a large set of files from another program (Mindware).
The function [is here](https://kzee.github.io/AggregatePhysio_Demo.html)

relevant code is:

```
mw <- function (filename) {
    require(readxl)
  require(magrittr)
    d <- read_excel(filename)
    names(d) <- NULL
    newd <- data.frame(
      row =  t(as.vector(d[6, 2:ncol(d)])) %>% as.numeric(), 
      video =  t(as.vector(d[3, 2:ncol(d)])) ,
      id = filename)
    newd <- subset(newd, is.na(time) == F)
  }

library(magrittr)
library(foreach)
library(plyr)
setwd("#set wd here")

my_physio_data <- ldply(.data = list.files(pattern="*.xlsx"),
              .fun = mw,
              .parallel = TRUE)
```

I've used it in the past with no issues- maybe 6 months ago. But now, I continually get an error:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : task 82 failed - "attempt to apply non-function"
```

the function `mw()` works on single files just fine. It's the second part using `ldply` where I'm unable to run.

I've downgraded plyr, upgraded plyr, reinstalled all my packages, but I can't actually figure out where this error comes from. The author also does not know.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: As far as i can see , it should work since ldply export the function mw. Does it work with ``.parallel = F`?

Comment: `plyr` is retired, if you don't need the parallel read in, you could try out `purrr::map_dfr` instead with your `mw` function

Comment: @RicVillalba it does not work with modified arguments, either.

Comment: @starja Thanks! I got this to work using ```purrr::map_dfr(list.files(pattern="*.xlsx"), mw)``` and also with ```do.call("rbind", lapply(list.files(pattern="*.xlsx"), mw))```.  Still not sure what the error is because it seems like it should would with the older version of ```plyr``` at least, but at least there is a workaround.